# Select multiple lines from text file

Tags: java, text, file-io

I am working on a program that will create a word cloud from words that are spoken by a candidate in the presidential debate. The way the text file is set up one person can speak for multiple lines and I want to take in all those lines so I can count the frequency of the words they spoke. There is also a list of `stop words` that will not be counted for the word cloud. Some examples of the `stop words` are: "is", "a", "the" and so on. So far I have been able to take in all the `stop words` and the entire transcript for the debate and remove the `stop words` from the transcript. Now I want to separate the transcript into what each candidate said and I'm having troubles with it since a person speaks for multiple lines. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ResendizYonzon {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       readTextFile("democratic-debate2015Oct13.txt");
   }

   public static String readTextFile(String text) throws FileNotFoundException {
       File f = new File(text);
       Scanner out = new Scanner(f);
       String word = "";
       File f1 = new File("stopwords.txt");
       Scanner out1 = new Scanner(f1);
       ArrayList<String> stopWords = new ArrayList<String>();
       ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
       while (out1.hasNext()) {
           stopWords.add(out1.next());
       }
       while (out.hasNext()) {
           words.add(out.next());
       }
       words.removeAll(stopWords);
       out.close();
       out1.close();
       return word;
   }
}
```

Transcript snippet:

```
CLINTON:  No.  I think that, like most people that I know, I have a range of views, but they are rooted in my values and my experience. And I don't take a back seat to anyone when it comes to progressive experience and progressive commitment.
You know, when I left law school, my first job was with the Children's Defense Fund, and for all the years since, I have been focused on how we're going to un-stack the deck, and how we're gonna make it possible for more people to have the experience I had.
You know, to be able to come from a grandfather who was a factory worker, a father who was a small business person, and now asking the people of America to elect me president.
COOPER:  Just for the record, are you a progressive, or are you a moderate?
CLINTON:  I'm a progressive.  But I'm a progressive who likes to get things done.  And I know...
(APPLAUSE)
...how to find common ground, and I know how to stand my ground, and I have proved that in every position that I've had, even dealing with Republicans who never had a good word to say about me, honestly. But we found ways to work together on everything from...
COOPER:  Secretary...
CLINTON:  ...reforming foster care and adoption to the Children's Health Insurance Program, which insures...
COOPER:  ...thank you...
CLINTON:  ...8 million kids.  So I have a long history of getting things done, rooted in the same values...
COOPER:  ...Senator...
CLINTON:  ...I've always had.
COOPER:  Senator Sanders.  A Gallup poll says half the country would not put a socialist in the White House.  You call yourself a democratic socialist.  How can any kind of socialist win a general election in the United States?
SANDERS:  Well, we're gonna win because first, we're gonna explain what democratic socialism is.
And what democratic socialism is about  is saying that it is immoral and wrong that the top one-tenth of 1 percent in this country own almost 90 percent - almost - own almost as much wealth as the bottom 90 percent.  That it is wrong, today, in a rigged economy, that 57 percent of all new income is going to the top 1 percent.
That when you look around the world, you see every other major country providing health care to all people as a right, except the United States.  You see every other major country saying to moms that, when you have a baby, we're not gonna separate you from your newborn baby, because we are going to have - we are gonna have medical and family paid leave, like every other country on Earth.
Those are some of the principles that I believe in, and I think we should look to countries like Denmark, like Sweden and Norway, and learn from what they have accomplished for their working people.
(APPLAUSE)
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Any errors?

Comment: No errors, just trying to figure out how to take in everything one specific candidate says. For example if the user wants Clinton then I just need everything Clinton said.

Comment: Hm, sorry, but I cannot believe that you don't have any idea how to solve this. How do YOU know which text is from Clinton? Hint: There is the speaker's name at the beginning of the line when the speaker changes. First identify the speaker names. Then each text right after a name until the next name or the end of the file is associated to this one speaker.

Comment: I know that. If everything was in one line it would be easy. But a person speaks for multiple lines and I'm having troubles figuring out how to take all of those lines.

Comment: Maybe it should be better to read the text line by line. Use a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) with its [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) method instead of a `Scanner`. Then split the line at white space and look for the first word. If it is all capitalized and ends with a colon, it is a speaker name. The following words are associated to this speaker. Read the next line. If the first word is not a speaker name, add the words to the last speaker, And so on.

Comment: You said if a user ask for Clinton? then you just need everything Clinton said. If that is true, would those everything make sense? because they are in response to other people. Do you mean, that all responses of Clinton should be concatenated into one?

Comment: And for the stopwords it is better to use a `HashSet<String>` instead of a list so it is faster to look up if a word is a stopword. And to count how often a word is used by one speaker use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` with the word as key and the number of occurrences as a value. If you want to count for every speaker, create such a hash map for each one like so: `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of problem in the question as well as in your comment to the question, you want to concatenate all speech given by a user into one, so that when a user asks for speech of a speaker `i.e. CLINTON` you just give them the parts of speech of `CLINTON`.

That is easy to accomplish. Which? the `colon (:)` is your ticket to solving this issue. If you look at the input file, whenever there is a new speaker the line starts with speaker name followed by colon.

What you need to do is following list of actions:

- Open the file
- Read the file line by line
- For each line check if the line contains colon (:) or not
- If the line contains colon then you need to split the line using colon as seperator
- Assuming that you don't have colons elsewhere, splitting the following line

  **COOPER:  Just for the record, are you a progressive, or are you a moderate?**

gives you the following tokens (assuming there are no colons elsewhere)

**Token[0] = COOPER**

**Token[1] = Just for the record, are you a progressive, or are you a moderate?**

- Now that you got two tokens, check if you are in just started reading transcript file or already have speakers
- If just started reading the file then you got your first speaker so add him and initialize the variables
- If already have other speakers then add the previous speaker (if not added yet) and update his/her speech before reading the speech of the new (or revisited) speaker.

If you continue above steps, every time you come across a speaker, you update the speech for it and add it to the hash map until the end of the line is reached.

Below is the sample code that would do above and is fully commented to help you understand it.

```
   //public static HashSet that stores your speakers.
   public static Map<String, String> speakerSpeech = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
       readTextFile("C:\\test_java\\transcript.txt");
   }

   public static void readTextFile(String text) throws FileNotFoundException {
       File f = new File(text);

       String line; 
       BufferedReader br; 
       try {
           //open input stream to the path passed as text
           FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(text);

           //open buffered reader using the input stream
           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

           //String builder used to append speech and lines (String is immutable) 
           StringBuilder speech = new StringBuilder(); 

           // currentSpeaker is used for history. when new speaker is found, we should know who was previous one
           // so we save all the speech that so far we have read
           String currentSpeaker = null; 

           // while loop keeps looping over file line by line and terminates when line == null
           // that is when end of file is reached. 
           while((line=br.readLine()) != null) {

               //if line contains : then it is a line having a speaker, based on structure of your input file
               if(line.contains(":")) {
                   //split the line using colon as seperator gives us 2 values (speaker and sentence) based
                   //on structure of your file
                   String[] chunks = line.split(":");

                   //store the speaker name CLINTON that was chunks[0] because left most value to colon
                   //triming whitespace (leading and trailing if any)
                   String speakerName = chunks[0].trim(); 

                   //condition to check if we just started reading transcripts or already read some
                   if(currentSpeaker == null) {
                       //just started reading transcript file, this is the first speaker ever
                       // assign the speaker to currentSpeaker
                       currentSpeaker = speakerName; 

                       //add the remainder of speech after colon : to the speech StringBuilder 
                       speech.append(chunks[1]); 
                   } else {
                       //else because currentSpeaker is not null, we already have read speakers before
                       //current speaker is old speaker and we are about to scan new speaker so

                       //condition to check if speaker is already added to out list of speakers
                       if(speakerSpeech.containsKey(currentSpeaker)) {
                           //yes speaker is already added in map, then get its previous speechs
                           String previousSpeech = speakerSpeech.get(currentSpeaker); 

                           //re-add the speaker in map and but this time with updated speech
                           //concatenating previous speech with current speech
                           speakerSpeech.put(currentSpeaker, previousSpeech + " >>> " + speech.toString()); 
                       } else {
                           //no speaker is new, then add it to the map with its speech
                           speakerSpeech.put(currentSpeaker, speech.toString()); 
                       }

                       //after storing previous speaker in list, add current speaker for record
                       currentSpeaker = speakerName.trim(); 

                       //initialize speech variable with new speakers speech after : colon
                       speech = new StringBuilder(chunks[1]); 
                   }
               } else {
                   //this else is because line did not have colon : hence, its continuation of speech 
                   // of current speaker, just append to the speech
                   speech.append(line); 
               }
           }

           //because last line == null and loop terminates, we have to add the last speaker's speech to 
           //the list manually. 
           if(speakerSpeech.containsKey(currentSpeaker)) {
               String previousSpeech = speakerSpeech.get(currentSpeaker); 
               speakerSpeech.put(currentSpeaker, previousSpeech + " >>> " + speech.toString()); 
           } else {
               speakerSpeech.put(currentSpeaker, speech.toString()); 
           }

           System.out.println("No. of speakers: " + speakerSpeech.size());
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           //handle error
       }

       //all speakers with their speech one giant string. 
       System.out.println(speakerSpeech.toString());
}
```

Executing the above gives you the following output:

```
{COOPER=  Just for the record, are you a progressive, or are you a moderate? >>>   Secretary... >>>   ...thank you... >>>   ...Senator... >>>   Senator Sanders.  A Gallup poll says half the country would not put a socialist in the White House.  You call yourself a democratic socialist.  How can any kind of socialist win a general election in the United States?, SANDERS=  Well, we're gonna win because first, we're gonna explain what democratic socialism is.And what democratic socialism is about  is saying that it is immoral and wrong that the top one-tenth of 1 percent in this country own almost 90 percent - almost - own almost as much wealth as the bottom 90 percent.  That it is wrong, today, in a rigged economy, that 57 percent of all new income is going to the top 1 percent.That when you look around the world, you see every other major country providing health care to all people as a right, except the United States.  You see every other major country saying to moms that, when you have a baby, we're not gonna separate you from your newborn baby, because we are going to have - we are gonna have medical and family paid leave, like every other country on Earth.Those are some of the principles that I believe in, and I think we should look to countries like Denmark, like Sweden and Norway, and learn from what they have accomplished for their working people.(APPLAUSE), CLINTON=  No.  I think that, like most people that I know, I have a range of views, but they are rooted in my values and my experience. And I don't take a back seat to anyone when it comes to progressive experience and progressive commitment.You know, when I left law school, my first job was with the Children's Defense Fund, and for all the years since, I have been focused on how we're going to un-stack the deck, and how we're gonna make it possible for more people to have the experience I had.You know, to be able to come from a grandfather who was a factory worker, a father who was a small business person, and now asking the people of America to elect me president. >>>   I'm a progressive.  But I'm a progressive who likes to get things done.  And I know...(APPLAUSE)...how to find common ground, and I know how to stand my ground, and I have proved that in every position that I've had, even dealing with Republicans who never had a good word to say about me, honestly. But we found ways to work together on everything from... >>>   ...reforming foster care and adoption to the Children's Health Insurance Program, which insures... >>>   ...8 million kids.  So I have a long history of getting things done, rooted in the same values... >>>   ...I've always had.}
```